# passing variable from data-attribute to onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have a page with table of a number of records in it

Each row has button on it I want to add an onclick event so it fires a popup message, if they ok it the page diverts to another page passing the value found in the data attribute but I cant get it to work

Jquery looks like this:

```
            var aFeatures = document.querySelectorAll(".sweet-roll");
        for (var i = 0; i < aFeatures.length; i++) {
                   aFeatures[i].onclick = function() {
                       swal({
                           title: "Rollback To Selected Version?",
                           text: "Are you sure you want to rollback to the selected version?",
                           type: "warning",
                           showCancelButton: true,
                           confirmButtonClass:  'btn-danger',
                           confirmButtonText:  'Yes, Rollback',
                           closeOnConfirm: false,
                           //closeOnCancel: false
                       },
                       function(){
                           window.location.href="/cms/rollback.aspx?id="+$(this).data('uuid');
                       });
                   };
               }
           };
```

So that every button with the class 'sweet-roll' gets the onclick event.

Each html row looks like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-app sweet-roll" data-uuid="97aaa88c-ac9f-11e4-807b-0026b9ba6b95"><i class="fa fa-reply-all"></i>Rollback</a>
```

But it keeps saying the value is undefined as if it cant find the data-uuid value?

Comment: Mixing jQuery and pure js? You can't use `$(this)` like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `this` is referencing SweetAlert caller, but not your element. What you need to do is to save it in some variable, let's say `_this`

```
    var aFeatures = document.querySelectorAll(".sweet-roll");

    for (var i = 0; i < aFeatures.length; i++) {
               aFeatures[i].onclick = function() {
                   var _this = this

                   swal({
                       title: "Rollback To Selected Version?",
                       text: "Are you sure you want to rollback to the selected version?",
                       type: "warning",
                       showCancelButton: true,
                       confirmButtonClass:  'btn-danger',
                       confirmButtonText:  'Yes, Rollback',
                       closeOnConfirm: false,
                       //closeOnCancel: false
                   },
                   function(){
                       window.location.href="/cms/rollback.aspx?id="+$(_this).data('uuid');
                   });
               };
           }
       };
```